# Posting to users wall while applying the app (facebook php sdk)

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

i am using basic facebook php sdk to login users to my page via facebook.
facebook.php, base_facebook.php and:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
header("Location: /");
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

and i want to allow my users to post (or skip)  something to their wall's when logging in. like that:
http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/web_dialog.png

any ideas?

Comment: As is, you have no authentication logic in this code example.  Please review the FB developer docs to find out how you can get a valid `access_token` when `getUser()` returns `False` in the case of a not-yet authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

to post to a user's wall you'd do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['status'])){
try {
 $post = stripslashes($_POST['status']);
    $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/<fb_user_id>/feed?access_token='.$session['access_token'], 'post', array('message'=> strip_tags($post), 'cb' => ''));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
         echo "<pre>";
         echo $e;
         echo "</p>";
}
}
```

You can style the form that posts to that script to match that in the png file. 
hope that is what you are looking for and helps you.